# Savepoint is not supported with memory optimized tables (EF core 5)

Tags: sql-server-2016, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

Upgrade EF core version 3.1 to 5 with new feature SavePoints (auto created when use transaction manual)

I have a memory-optimized table in SQL Server 2016 called "Content".

When I call the "SaveChanges" command the system throws an exception "Creating a savepoint is not supported with memory optimized tables." How can I turn off savepoints ?

NOTE: If I use TransactionScope then pass success.

Please give me the solution to handle this situation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Comment: Instead of turning off savepoints, *don't use an explicit transaction*. A savepoint is only used when you use an explicit transaction. In most cases though, this isn't needed. `SaveChanges` *already* uses an internal transaction. DbContext already implements Unit-of-Work semantics, so there's no need for an explicit transaction.

Comment: Why are you using explicit transactions anyway? Did you try to use the "generic repository" **anti**pattern? In that case you should check [No need for Repository and Unit-of-Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) and [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using the unitofwork model for my project. I have 2 tables A and B that do not force foreign keys. I add new record to table A and save to DB and generate id. After that, I add the information record to table B with the id generated from table A earlier. I have to wrap it all in one explicit transaction for data integrity

Comment: That's your bug. You don't need an extra Unit-of-Work, you already have a perfectly good one. `I have to wrap it all in one explicit transaction for data integrity ` no you don't, you **broke integrity** when you used the repository antipattern, now you have to cover this up by adding another transaction. Don't do that

Comment: Read the links I posted. You don't need another UoW on top of the existing one. By trying to execute one `SaveChanges` after each "CRUD" operation, you broke UoW and had to introduce a transaction. And yet, your `INSERT` can easily perform 30 UPDATES and 60 DELETES along with another 41 INSERTs, instead of the single `Insert` you thought you wrote

Comment: I have read the link you sent. I understand all crud is wrapped in one command savechanges. but I don't understand what you mean “And yet, your INSERT can easily perform 30 UPDATES and 60 DELETES along with another 41 INSERTs, instead of the single Insert you thought you wrote”

Comment: Then you didn't understand it at all. A DbContext caches all changes and executes **all of them** when you call `SaveChanges`. That's why it doesn't need an external transaction. When you write an `Insert()` that adds a new item to the context and calls `SaveChanges`, what gets saved is *all cached changes*, not just the last one. That's why all those "generic repositories" floating around are antipatterns and actually pretty bad code. They break the abstraction, harm performance by using long-running transactions *and* produce logically incorrect results. Don't use them. They aren't needed

Comment: A DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work. A DbSet already is a Repository. When you try to put a "generic repository" on top of EF Core you're trying to put a lower-level abstraction on top of a higher level one. They just don't fit, they go the other way round.

Comment: “what gets saved is all cached changes, not just the last one”... 
I injected the dependency with the scope "AddScoped ProductUow" and all the commands write to the database correspond to only one request. did i misunderstand?

Comment: Please post your code. DI has nothing to do with this discussion. You don't need to call `SaveChanges` multiple time. Just once when eg a Controller action is ready to exit, is enough. If you do that, you don't need to use external transactions. If you don't use external transactions, you won't have errors about savepoints. It looks like it would be easier to just clean up the code instead of talking about how to clean it.

Answer (score 0):

I want to insert row into two table without foreign key.

**in startup.cs file**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHealthChecks();
        services.AddDbContext<wUtilityContentContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(
           Algorithm.Decrypt(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:wUtilityContent_ConnectionString"]),
           b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name)));

        services.AddUnitOfWorkPool(optionsBuilder =>
        {
            optionsBuilder.AddUnitOfWork<wUtilityContentContext>("Content");
        });
        services.AddScoped<IContentUow, ContentUow>();
        services.AddScoped<AuditCoreLog>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        ....
    }
```

**In ContentService.cs file**

```
public class ContentServices : ContentServiceBase
{
    private readonly AuditCoreLog _auditLog;
    private readonly IContentUow _contentUow;
    public ContentServices(IContentUow contentUow, AuditCoreLog auditLog)
    {
        _contentUow = contentUow;
        _auditLog = auditLog;
    }
    public override Task<MessageResponse> CategoryInsertUpdate(CategoryInsertUpdate_Request request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var response = new MessageResponse() { };
        try
        {
            int _RESPONSE_EXISTED_CATE = -2;
            int _RESPONSE_NOT_EXISTS_CATE = -3;
            int _nHotOrder = 0;
            var findnHotOrder = _contentUow.Category.Where(p => p.ParentId == request.ParentId).ToList();
            if (findnHotOrder != null && findnHotOrder.Count > 0)
               _nHotOrder = findnHotOrder.Max(x => x.OrderNo).GetValueOrDefault();
            var insertCategory = _contentUow.Category.Add(new TblCategory()
            {
                    ParentId = request.ParentId,
                    Alias = request.Alias,
                    OrderNo = _nHotOrder + 1,
                    Status = request.Status,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatedUser = request.CreatedUser,
                    SystemId = request.SystemId,
                    ImageUrl = request.ImageUrl
            });

                _contentUow.SaveChanges(); //savechange to DB -> get id identity
                var _categoryId = insertCategory.Entity.Id;
                var insertCategoryContent_vi = _contentUow.CategoryContent.Add(new TblCategoryContent()
                {
                    CategoryId = _categoryId,
                    CategoryName = request.CategoryNameVi,
                    CategoryContent = request.CategoryContentVi,
                    LanguageId = (int)PaymentApps_PaymentLanguage.VN
                });

                var insertCategoryContent_en = _contentUow.CategoryContent.Add(new TblCategoryContent()
                {
                    CategoryId = _categoryId,
                    CategoryName = request.CategoryNameEn,
                    CategoryContent = request.CategoryContentEn,
                    LanguageId = (int)PaymentApps_PaymentLanguage.EN
                });
            _contentUow.SaveChanges();
            _contentUow.CommitTransaction();
            response.ResponseStatus = ErrorCodes.SUCCESS;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.ResponseStatus = ErrorCodes.SYSTEM_ERROR;
            _contentUow.RollbackTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```